# T-SQL : unwanted data conversion failing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff, dateadd

I'm trying to group data into seconds. Currently, I use a T-SQL query to break down SQL data into minutes.

```
SELECT TOP 200   
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TIMESTAMP) / @Value) * @Value, 0) 'TIMESTAMP',
    COUNT(Something) AS '# of Sessions' 
FROM
    table WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    TIMESTAMP BETWEEN @Start AND @End  
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TIMESTAMP) / @Value) * @Value, 0)
ORDER BY
    COUNT(Something) DESC
```

This returns the information I'm looking for by minute. What I want to do is pull the same information by second, but I continue to encounter issues with a conversion. I don't want it to move to an int, I would prefer it to stay datetime, since I want it by seconds. I've tried a convert, but received the same result.

```
SELECT TOP 200   
    DATEADD(SECOND, (DATEDIFF_BIG(SECOND, 0, TIMESTAMP) / @Value) * @Value, 0) 'TIMESTAMP',
    COUNT(Something) AS '# of Sessions' 
FROM
    table WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    TIMESTAMP BETWEEN @Start AND @End  
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(SECOND, (DATEDIFF_BIG(SECOND, 0, TIMESTAMP) / @Value) * @Value, 0)
ORDER BY
    COUNT(Something) DESC
```

The error occurs on the timestamp in the select statement

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do here. Why the `/@Value*@Value`, what's that supposed to do?

Comment: Try to cast to bigint.  `CAST(DATEDIFF_BIG(SECOND, 0, TIMESTAMP) AS BIGINT)`

Comment: DATEDIFF_BIG returns a bigint. I tried anyways and got the same error. Thank you though.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - @ Value is an int that for this exercise is set to 1. The Datediff_BIG logic takes the difference between the value found in the row for TIMESTAMP, and then adds 1 to another record. This in effect would be 08/23/2022 14:01:01 and 08/23/2022 14:01:02. The goal of this query is to pull all records that happened within that one second, but on a much larger scale; that's why a simple WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN XXX and XXX will not work

Comment: Here's an example of the results using the one minute version of the query

`Time  #
2022-08-15 14:07:00.000 200879
2022-08-15 14:08:00.000 192645
2022-08-15 14:09:00.000 210339`

Comment: Wouldn't a cast to [smalldatetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) accomplish the same thing? If you just want to ignore the time fractions, that would be a lot simpler

Comment: @HoneyBadger - Can you explain more? I like simple

Comment: @freakostudent `smalldatetime` is a datetime datatype with just date, hours, minutes, seconds. Seems to be what you are looking for. This `DATEDIFF` is hard to understand, a simple cast is easier to read, and likely will help performance too. See the link in my previous comment

Comment: I suspect the you're trying to convert UNIX Timestamps.  Please post the datatype for the TIMESTAMP column and a few examples.  If you can, post the expected date/time that the UNIX Timestamp should be converted to so we can tell what the resolution of the original timestamp is.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have `DATEADD_BIG`. But in your case, you can just do your truncation calculation from a different epoch, such as `20100101`

Other notes:

- Do not use `NOLOCK`, it can cause serious data integrity issues.
- `COUNT(Something)` counts non-null values, rather than distinct values. DId you mean `COUNT(*)`?
- `BETWEEN` is generally a bad idea with dates, use a half-open interval `>= AND <`
- Note that `TIMESTAMP` in the `WHERE` refers to the original value, not the calculated value.
- Use `[]` to quote column names, rather than `''`. Ideally don't use columns that need quoting.

```sql
SELECT TOP (200)
    DATEADD(second, (DATEDIFF(second, '20100101', TIMESTAMP) / @Value) * @Value, '20100101') TIMESTAMP,
    COUNT(Something) AS [# of Sessions] 
FROM
    [table]
WHERE
    TIMESTAMP >= @Start
    AND TIMESTAMP < @End  
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(second, (DATEDIFF(second, '20100101', TIMESTAMP) / @Value) * @Value, '20100101')
ORDER BY
    COUNT(Something) DESC;
```

In the new SQL Server 2022, you can actually just use [`DATE_BUCKET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```sql
SELECT TOP (200)
    DATE_BUCKET(second, @Value, TIMESTAMP) TIMESTAMP,
    COUNT(Something) AS [# of Sessions] 
FROM
    [table]
WHERE
    TIMESTAMP >= @Start
    AND TIMESTAMP < @End  
GROUP BY
    DATE_BUCKET(second, @Value, TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY
    COUNT(Something) DESC;
```